# Hibernate Criteria Optimization

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I was going through the old code in one of our application and found the below scenario.

```
 public <T> List<T> getList(boolean isTrue,String name,String empid)
 {
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(myType);
  criteria.add(Expression.eq("name",name)) ;
  if(isTrue&&empid!=null){
     criteria.add(Expression.eq("id",empid)) ;
  }
  List<T> result = criteria.list();
  return list;
}
```

Also the function is called two times like below.

```
List<T> employeeList = getList(true,name,empId);
if(employeeList.size()==0)
 employeeList = getList(false,name,null);
```

The reason behind this scenario is that sometimes the employeeId won't be correct. In that case we need to do a search only on employee name.

My doubts.

1) If am executing it this way am I querying the database twice ?

2) If yes then is there any way I can optimize it ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case Hibernate will execute the query twice since the parameters are differents.

You can configure query cache and second level cache to improve the performance.

The query cache will return the employeeIds and the second level cache will return the Employee data.

Comment: I dont want to configure it at cache, I want to modify the query to achieve the same.